# Creating Unity games for older versions of Android?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

[Android](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zUChf.png)

In the Unity editor, the lowest available Android version for debugging is Android 2.3.1 In my case, I have a phone running an older version of Android and I intend to publish my game to a wide audience. With the lowest version being 2.3.1, I see a problem publishing my games to older smartphones which  still occupy a considerable size of the market share. My question is: Is there a way to publish my game to older versions of Android? Or is it impossible?

Comment: You're talking about a 0.2% market share: http://www.statista.com/statistics/271774/share-of-android-platforms-on-mobile-devices-with-android-os/ Not really worth it, and, afaik, not possible.

Comment: Sorry, I did not formulate my question very well. What I meant is that 0.2% still represents a relatively large number of smartphones, especially in developing countries.

Comment: Then your only option is Unity 4.2 or earlier iirc.

Comment: But that would mean publishing two different versions of the same game: one for the newer smartphones and one for the old ones. Am I right?

Comment: I would say so, yes.

Comment: @Bart Do you think it's worth incorporating your comments into an answer? Granted, this question isn't likely to come up often (especially as time wears on), but could be useful to new developers aiming for legacy support. (And at least would give something for the OP to accept.)

Answer (score 3):

Versions later than Unity 4.2.x don't support Android versions earlier than 2.3.x. So if your project relies on functionality only present in 4.3.x and higher, you're out of luck.

Otherwise you can still download a 4.2.x or earlier version of Unity and create your builds with that.